# A poetic/literary term for "Ice Age"?

Tags: synonyms, poetry

Is there a poetic/literary term for "Ice Age" (besides "glacial epoch")?

Comment: The frozen era!

Comment: You could call it [*Gunz, Mindel, Riss,*](http://www.oocities.org/in2ourpast/pleistocene.htm) or (my favourite) ***Wurm***. In a poetic/literary context probably only the last is relevant, since it might be difficult to argue that "true humans" even *existed* at the time of the earlier ones.

Comment: Um, do you mean **poetic/literary** ?  I think you do.  At least, I really hope you do.  I'm not sure T.E.D. realised...

Comment: @itsbruce - I think you must be right. I edited the OP's 'literally' to 'literal' without considering the possibility that they really meant 'literary'. I have now fixed it; if I have misunderstood the OP's intention, they are still free to change it again.

Answer (score 6):

[**Fimbulwinter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fimbulwinter).  In Norse mythology, it is the mighty winter which precedes Ragnarok - the war that ends the world.  It is an image that has been used often in Scandinavian literature since - and some SF and Fantasy English Language writings.

Answer (score 5):

You probably won't find any non-mythological terms in English. The whole idea of Ice Ages having happened in the distant past didn't really get figured out until the late 1800s, so it's pretty unlikely that Shakespeare or his contemporaries would ever have come up with anything to describe them.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions off the top of my head. I added an asterisk after terms I made up. If you're going for something poetic, I assume you can invent your own term?

-The Age of Ice*
-The Glacial Period
-The Pleistocene Epoch (when the most recent Ice Age occurred)
-The Long Winter*
-The Cold Age*

I could propose some more esoteric terms, but I don't want to get too wacky. I hope these help.

Answer (score 2):

One word I've seen in writing is *glaciation*. This word implicitly acknowledges that there are multiple incidents of this (which there have been).

Climate scientists tend to prefer the term *glacial* (short for [glacial period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_age#Glacials_and_interglacials)) to refer to a bad (cold and ice-covered) part of the cycle. The warmer periods are called *interglacials*, and the entire epoch is of course called the [Pleistocene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleistocene).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Rime Age. It sounds poetic to me.  http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=rime&searchmode=none

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is 'the Big Freeze', which has been used for a cold period occurring about 12,800 years ago (see the news stories [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2756224/Do-tiny-diamonds-prove-Big-Freeze-caused-cosmic-impact-Nanocrystals-hint-asteroid-hit-Earth-12-800-years-ago.html) and [here](http://www.livescience.com/42728-cold-age-wiped-out-forests.html)).

Comment: I've heard "Big Freeze" to refer to the final outcome of our universe's expansion and cooling. Interesting to see it used for past periods as well.

Comment: The 'Big Freeze' is what sets in when you truthfully answer the perennial question 'Does my ass/bottom look big in this?'

Comment: @smci - Once frostbitten, twice lie...  :)